# SAS Looping 1 Dice Easy Concept Long explanation

Tags: loops, sas

I came across this little problem about looping but I am not sure how to go about it. This is how the problem goes.

Two players are interested in having a game of dice. A single dice is rolled until either 
a five, followed immediately by a six appears, or alternatively, a six, followed 
immediately by another six. We are interested in which event is more likely to occur 
first, a 5/6 pair, or a 6/6 pair? The players aren’t sure if the game is fair, and would 
like to investigate.

So I have a data set called work.dice with 10 000 observations representing 10 000 roles of a dice (1 "x" variable that takes values 1 to 6 with equal probability so its just 10 000 observations with numbers 1 to 6 in no particular order). Now every time we obtain either a 5/6 or a 6/6 the game is restarted. For example, rolling 5/6/6 counts as a 5/6, but not as a 6/6. I have to use the SAS data set work.dice to create two new SAS data sets fivesix, and sixsix, each containing the one variable, NumRolls. The variable NumRolls indicates the number of dice rolls it took since the last restart.

My understanding of this is that, for example, is if the first 7 numbers are 2,3,5,4,1,3,4, and then the 8thth and 9th are 5,6, the fivesix data set needs to record a "9" for variable "NumRolls". Then if the next say 3 numbers are 1,5,4 but then the 2 after that are 6,6 we record a 5 for "NumRolls" in data set sixsix.

I'm struggling to work with "If-Then do" statements and loops so I would deeply appreciate any help.

Comment: This sounds like homework! What have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Well I am trying to work with If-Then Do statements and an accumulating variable which returns to a value of 0 after outputting but I can't figure out how to say "If the current value observation is 5 and the next observation is 6 then output to fivesix" or "if the current observation is 6 but the previous observation is 5 then output to five six" and similarly with the 6/6 case... but well im stuck. Its meant to introduce the concept of looping  but the only benefit I get from it is learning how to loop :/ Right now I just get errors.

Comment: Do you have to use a loop? Seems you could solve this a lot easier using a retained value from one row to the next (or a lagged value)

Comment: I could see using a loop if you're going to use the `point` option, but that's a terrible way to solve the problem.  This sounds like an example taken from a `c++` book or something and then used in SAS.  If this is online somewhere, a link to it would be good as it might give us context for why you're asking this question this way.

Comment: I think that's the thing I was missing. Just that lag(x) function. Thanks I think I can work it out. I just didn't know how to compare one observations to a consecutive one! Thank you.

Comment: @user3435733  Be very careful with the lag() function.  It is easily misused.  Personally I prefer using a retained variable to using the lag() function as there are no unexpected results.

Comment: `lag` does not compare an observation to another observation.  It creates a queue that you can then use to compare to the value in the next observation.  This is a small but important distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're asking a conceptual question, i'll answer in kind.  If you want to then work through some of the programming and ask a more concrete programming question, please feel free to ask a new question.

First off, this doesn't require looping.  There are a few different approaches to this, but none of the more common ones require coding a loop.  That's because SAS will happily perform the only loop you need for you - the data step loop.  That's what pulls in each new observation and performs the same code against each one.

The concepts you need to solve this using the simplest set of tools:

- Counter variable.  You need to understand how to keep a counter that `retain`s its value from one row to the next, plus how to perform simple operations such as resetting it to zero at appropriate times.
- A way to compare a value in one observation to a value in a different observation.  This requires learning one of two techniques; either using a `lag` queue, or learning how to `retain` a value from the previous observation in a new variable, plus re-setting that variable when appropriate.
- How to construct and evaluate an `if` statement to determine if the condition you are interested in is true or not.  `if/then/do` is the right idea here; you need to learn how to use that.

If the last bit is causing you trouble, then you should ask a question about how to use `if/then/do` construction where you give a simple example of how you're trying to use it - don't use this problem as your example, use as simple of an example as possible so you drill down to the core of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Create 10000 Random Rolls of Dice*/
data dice;
    do i=1 to 10000;
        x = int(ranuni(0) * 6 + 1);
        output;
    end;
run;

/* Partition Rolls to Datasets fivesix sixsix based on outcome*/
/* Data step creates two new datasets fivesix and sixsix from a provided dataset*/
/* The dataset dice is approximated above*/
/* For the first row in the datastep a new variable run_count is initialized*/
/* run_count takes the value 0 to begin*/
/* To increment run_count across rows, a retain statement is used*/
/* The lag function is used to create a new variable x_lag do allow reading both */
/* the current and previous rolls at the same time*/
/* In the event of a 5 followed by 6 or 6 followed by six, */
/* a count of how long it has been since the counter has been reset is calculated, */
/* the counter is reset, and the combination is outputted to the proper dataset*/
/* If neither combination is met, the counter simply increments. */
data fivesix sixsix;
    set dice;
    if _n_ = 1 then run_count = 0;
    retain run_count;
    x_lag = lag(x);
    if x = 6 and x_lag = 5 then do;
        NumRolls = run_count + 1;
        run_count = 0;
        output fivesix;
    end;
    else if x = 6 and x_lag = 6 then do;
        NumRolls = run_count + 1;
        run_count = 0;
        output sixsix;
    end;
    else do;
        run_count = run_count+1;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: I'm just wondering if you used the "by i" for a particular reason (like to preserve order or something)? I tried dropping the i variable from the dice dataset and removing the 'by i;" line and it seems to work alright. Is there any consequence of doing it like this?

Comment: I'm downvoting this. While it's a fine answer to the homework problem, it shouldn't be provided to the question above.  It doesn't have any explanation to help the user learn, and more importantly it's just giving an answer when really what's needed is learning enough to be able to come *up* with the answer.

Comment: Thats your choice, but given I'm just trying to answer with factually actual responses to get enough points to upvote something I found very interesting myself... I consider it in poor taste. Sometimes the best thing to see when you are starting out is an example.

Comment: Joe I appreciate that you want to go to the extra length to make sure I am not being lazy and asking for a quick answer but I assure you I am not the type of person who does that. I really did learn a lot from this one example and took time to understand each step so thank you JJFord3.

Comment: @JJFord3 This is more of a community thing: we don't answer homework questions with code dumps.  It probably deserves a downvote homework or not because it doesn't explain at all what's going on; a good answer does both, but I tend to not downvote in those cases.  But in this case, we have a 'teach a man to fish' approach here on Stack Overflow: if the question includes code and is specific, we answer in kind, if it's more general like above, we answer with concepts.

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) has a very good explanation of how the community has decided to treat this subject.

Comment: You assumed negative intent. I assumed positive intent. You gave no code examples. I gave one. user345733 obviously found it helpful and even found some extraneous code. I feel this was a successful exchange as measured by its outcome regardless of your position.

Comment: There isn't an assumption of intent - that's part of the point of that linked question from [meta.se].  We don't care whether someone's trying to cheat their homework or not: we are happy to help with homework.  But the question and answer have to be generally useful, not just giving them the answer for their homework question.  This applies to _any_ question/answer no matter the source: an answer should be detailed and explain why/how rather than just code, and a question should not generally ask for a complete solution to an entire project.

Comment: @JJFord3  Thanks for updating your answer with some detail, but you shouldn't put it in block comments like that; it's very hard to read.  Put the explanation of what you're doing in plan text in the answer, before the code - or interspersed, if that makes more sense.